# Union from Multiple Tables in many databases and group results in batches of n

Tags: t-sql, group-by, powershell, union

First post in dba, so please be gentle.

I have a project I am working through and have 4+ SQL Server databases to work with.

These DBs contain 2 (or more tables) I wish to UNION the results from.

The data I am interested in contains Windows Server file paths (SrcFilename, DestFilename for reference) and looks something like this:

> srcfilename001.dwg|\\srcServer1\path\to\file\|destfilename001.dwg|\\destserver\path\to\file\
>   srcfilename002.dwg|\\srcServer2\path\to\file\|destfilename002.dwg|\\destserver\path\to\file\
>   srcfilename003.dwg|\\srcServer3\path\to\file\|destfilename003.dwg|\\destserver\random\path\
>   srcfilename004.dwg|\\srcServer4\path\to\file\|destfilename004.dwg|\\destserver\random\path\

I have been able to UNION the data using a query like this:

```
    SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM [Database_015].[dbo].[CAD_DATA] Where [Database_015].[dbo].[CAD_DATA].[UniqueValue] = 1 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM [Database_016].[dbo].[CAD_DATA] Where [Database_016].[dbo].[CAD_DATA].[UniqueValue] = 1 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM [Database_017].[dbo].[CAD_DATA] Where [Database_017].[dbo].[CAD_DATA].[UniqueValue] = 1 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM [Database_020].[dbo].[CAD_DATA] Where [Database_020].[dbo].[CAD_DATA].[UniqueValue] = 1 
) A  
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Which works great...

I get the data I need in a random order rather than a bunch of files from \\server1, \\server2, \\server3 etc.

Obviously the randomness is because of the `ORDER BY NEWID()`.

The reason for gathering the data is because we're migrating millions of files and ultimately need to hash both the source and destination files to see if they match.

Ultimately I will use Powershell to hash the files from the resultant data and I *think* that having each Powershell `Start-ThreadJob 'Job'` point at each server in turn for `n` files will be faster than having it work on a "stripe" of data across multiple servers.

Thanks for your time. :)

Edit: The first comment asked for more explanation so here goes:

I don't know how to combine both `UNION ALL`, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` to produce a dataset from multiple different database tables that has `n` batches of files grouped by server in a random order.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; That's just it though, I don't have an approach. I know this sounds a bit like _"I've tried nothing and I'm all out of ideas"_ and to some extent it is, but I'm old enough to know my limitations when it comes to stuff like this and I find it better to ask for help before spending hours working stuff out for myself. (especially when time is short on a project like this)

Comment: @AlexFielder - assuming your sample source data, what do you want the results from a query to be?  Do the results from each individual select in your example represent rows from a single source server?

Comment: Hi @ScottHodgin, the results would I hope look like this: `srcfilename001.dwg|\\srcServer1\path\to\file\|destfilename001.dwg|\\destserver\path\to\file\ srcfilename002.dwg|\\srcServer2\path\to\file\|destfilename002.dwg|\\destserver\path\to\file\ srcfilename003.dwg|\\srcServer3\path\to\file\|destfilename003.dwg|\\destserver\random\path\ srcfilename004.dwg|\\srcServer4\path\to\file\|destfilename004.dwg|\\destserver\random\path\` with `n` rows of data relating to each srcserver so that I can match the `n` number when I process with Powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the question is...

> "*I've randomised per-server, but now I need to randomize among the whole set*"

...then it may be prudent to remove `UNION` & `ORDER BY` from your query altogether. You can unify a standard query against all database/server combinations into a single dataset stored as a PSCustomObject and pipe the unified data into [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) using the expression `{Get-Random}` to randomise among the whole set rather than per-call implicit partitions.

You can try something like the following using [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/).

```
$connections = @"
Server,Database
sql-01,Database_015
sql-01,Database_016
sql-02,Database_017
sql-03,Database_020
@" | ConvertFrom-Csv

$query_tmp = @"
select 
    '{0}' as serv,
    '{1}' as db,
    SrcFilename,
    DestFilename
from dbo.CAD_DATA
where UniqueValue = 1;
"@

$table = foreach($conn in $connections){
    $query = $query_tmp -f $conn.Server, $conn.Database
    Invoke-DbaQuery -Query $query -Server $conn.Server -Database $conn.Database
}

$table | Sort-Object {Get-Random} | Export-Csv ~/Desktop/myquery.csv
```

If you don't have access to / can't be bothered with dbatools, you may be able to use [`Invoke-SqlCmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd) in lieu of `Invoke-DbaQuery`

Comment: That's brilliant, Thank you @Peter Vandivier! (I only recently discovered dbatools and the more I see of it the more I like it!)